# Why does sleep after render in a Rails Controller Action delay the response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my API-only Rails application (rails 6.0.3.6, puma 6.4.0), I'm noticing unexpected delays after calling `render(json: { ... }, status: :ok)` for responses with large JSON data in my local environment, which I think might be linked to garbage collection. Interestingly, this issue doesn't occur in our staging or production environments.

I explored further, and just rendered an error and then put a sleep:

```rb
def index
  render(json: { error: 'Something' }, status: :unprocessable_entity)
  sleep 10 # Render is delayed in localhost
end
```

In staging, the front-end app (VueJS) doesn't wait for sleep 10. However, in my local development environment, front-end, the sleep 10 delays the response to the front-end.

Here's my puma.rb configuration for reference:

```rb
max_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }
min_threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MIN_THREADS") { max_threads_count }

threads min_threads_count, max_threads_count

port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }
pidfile ENV.fetch("PIDFILE") { "tmp/pids/server.pid" }
workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") { Etc.nprocessors }

preload_app!
plugin :tmp_restart
```

I'm trying to understand:

1. Why does the `sleep` call affect the response time even after `render` has been called?
2. Is this behaviour specific to the development environment or the configuration of the Rails server?
3. How does Rails handle code execution in a controller action after the `render` method?
4. Are there any potential fixes?

Any insights or explanations about this behavior would be greatly appreciated.